# Writing a query to see if a child exists in a different table and showing that existence in the template

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I have a simple app that creates a Log entry for that day for each Child of a Parent when something happens to the Child.

So, for example, a Parent contains three Children.

Each time a Child is interacted with, I create an entry in the Log table to log the action. The Log is organized by day. So I could have 3 entries for three Children on Tuesday and 4 entries for the same three Children on Wednesday.

I want to write a query that checks to see if the Child exists in the Log for that day. So when the page loads, or is refreshed, I set a template variable that indicates that it does exist on the log.

I've been thinking that the following query will sort out what I need. But I'm having a hard time figuring out the missing parts.

Models:

```
class Child(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()

class Log(models.Model):
    child = models.ForeignKey(Child, related_name="child_log")
    day = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)

class Parent(models.Model):
    parent_children = models.ManyToManyField(Child, blank=True, null=True)
```

Queryset:

```
today = date.today()
children = Child.objects.filter(parent=parent.id) <= parent.id comes from request kwargs
child_list = Child.objects.filter(id__contains=children.id)
does_exist = Log.objects.filter(child=child_list.id).filter(day=today)
```

But then I want to add that does_exist status to each Child in the template. That way I can show a different state if the Child has been logged or not.

Think of it like a todo list with todo items that can be done repeatedly in a day. If it's been done in a day, we need to show that it has been done. If it hasn't, then we can show that it hasn't.

I hope that is clear enough. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Is there any relations in models? Show your models

Comment: I added in the example models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm... If I understand correctly, try this

```
{% for child in childs %}
    {% if child.child_log.today.exists %}
    #do your staff
...
```

And write manager to Log:

```
class LogManager(models.Manager)
    def today(self)
        return self.get_query_set().filter(day=datetime.datetime.today())

...
class Log(models.Model):
    child = models.ForeignKey(Child, related_name="child_log")
    day = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)

    objects = LogManager()
```